# I was denied US visa

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, overstaying

I have been to the US 2 times, in 2007 and in 2010, with J1 visa. The second time I overstayed. After expiring J1 visa and I applied for student visa (I went to a language course) to prolong it till march 2011. It expired, too, and I overstayed till june, 2011. I left the US by myself (not deported).

I applied again in 2017 to get a tourist visa to the US but I was denied. I don't want to stay in the US, just would like to see that amazing country again.

What do you suggest me to do?
I am married, 2 kids and have nice job, property, land, bank statement in my country.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the refusal letter with your personal details blanked out?

Comment: I have dont have a refusal letter with me. I think that was 214 (b) section.

Answer (score 7):

You overstayed your US visa by less than six months which would mean you do not have a bar to entry even if you accumulated unlawful presence.

> Under section 212(a)(9)(B) of the Act, an alien is inadmissible if the
>   alien has accrued a specified period of unlawful presence, leaves the
>   United States after accruing the unlawful presence, and then seeks
>   admission during the period specified in (either 3 years or 10 years
>   after the departure, depending on the section 212(a)(9)(B)(i) duration
>   of the accrued unlawful presence)

and

> (B) [ALIENS UNLAWFULLY PRESENT](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html#0-0-0-2633).-
>
> (i) In general.-Any alien (other than an alien lawfully admitted for
>   permanent residence) who-
>
> (I) was unlawfully present in the United States for a period of more
>   than 180   days but less than 1 year, voluntarily departed the United
>   States (whether or   not pursuant to section   244(e)) prior to the
>   commencement of proceedings under   section   235(b)(1) or section
>   240, and again seeks admission within 3 years of   the date of such
>   alien's departure or removal, or

Also you were on a J visa which typically have Duration of Stay hence you did not accumulate unlawful presence during your overstay.

Thus from your 214(b) denial it appears the consular is not convinced you do not plan to immigrate to the USA. It would appear this is directly related to your overstay. Almost thing happened to me in 1999 where although I did not overstay, I spent more time than I told the consular officer I would at the interview.

You are married with children and already established in your country and hence there is not much you can do to improve your situation, it is already good.

You can either **get an immigration lawyer to apply on your behalf (not much they can do considering your situation) or wait a few more years and reapply**.

Comment: In the mean time, there are another two-hundred-and-some other countries that can be visited, most of them probably amazing in at least one way!